# Magento 2 Discount Amount is not showing on checkout cart summary?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

Discount Amount is not showing on the checkout cart summary

The discount is applied fine but not showing

I changed the theme to luma but still not showing.

[image]

Comment: are you using custom extension to show discount?

Comment: I'm using this extension Mageworld Magento 2 maximum coupon discount.

Comment: that the issue is in that extension, please put the code